# static variables

Tags: c

can anyone explain when static variables should be used and why?

Comment: Rarely, if ever. For the most part, not outside systems programming.

Comment: Why the downvote? That sounds like an academic question, but if that is actually part of an assignment, then that's a crappy assignment. But on the other hand, it's a good general question that in my opinion deserves to be answered on SO. (if not duplicated)

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 distinct uses of the `static` keyword in C:

- Static declarations in a function's scope
- Static declarations outside of a function's scope

---

### (MOSTLY) EVIL: Static Variables in a function

A static variable in a function is used as a "memory" state.

Basically, your variable is initialized to your default value only the first time you call it, and then retains its previous value in all the future calls.

It is potentially useful if you need to remember such state, but the use of such statics is usually **frowned upon** because they are pretty much **global variables in disguise**: they will consume your memory until the termination of your process once.

So, *in general*, making localized functions is **EVIL** / **BAD**.

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>


void  ping() {
  static int counter = 0;

  return (++counter);
}

int   main(int ac, char **av) {
  print("%d\n", ping()); // outputs 1
  print("%d\n", ping()); // outputs 2
  return (0);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
```

---

### (MOSTLY) GOOD: Static Variables outside of a function's scope

You can use static outside of a function on a variable or function (which, after all, is sort of a variable as well and points to a memory address).

What it does is limit the use of that variable to the file containing it. You cannot call it from somewhere else. While it still means that that function/var is "global" in the sense that it consumes your memory until your program's termination, at least it has the decency to not pollute your "namespace".

This is interesting because that way you can have small utility functions with identical names in different files of your project.

So, *in general*, making localized functions is **GOOD**.

**Example:**

*example.h*

```
#ifndef __EXAMPLE_H__
# define __EXAMPLE_H__

void  function_in_other_file(void);

#endif
```

*file1.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "example.h"

static void  test(void);


void test(void) {
  printf("file1.c: test()\n");
}

int   main(int ac, char **av) {
  test();  // calls the test function declared above (prints "file1.c: test()")
  function_in_other_file();
  return (0);
}
```

*file2.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "example.h"

static void  test(void); // that's a different test!!


void test(void) {
  printf("file2.c: test()\n");
}

void   function_in_other_file(void) {
  test();  // prints file2.c: test()
  return (0);
}
```

**Output:**

```
file1.c: test()
file2.c: test()
```

***PS***: Don't start throwing stones at me if you're a purist: I know static vars are not evil, they're not exactly globals either, functions are not exactly variables, and there's no actual "namespace" (don't get started on symbols) in C. But that's for the sake of the explanation here.

### Resources

- [Static Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)
- [Is a Static Variable in C Reallocated Every Time I Call a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703980/is-static-variable-in-c-re-allocated-everytime-calling-a-function)
- [A Draft of the ANSI C standard (C89)](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16306895/Draft-ANSI-C-Rationale)

Comment: Actually, they are more like globals than you say. Static local variables are generally stored in .bss or .data and initialized at either load time or compile time.

Comment: @Nathon: hey, didn't even know that. Great, thanks!

Comment: @Nathon: I'm asking you but anyone else is fine really, and I don't have a machine with a C compiler at hand... What happens if you make a function declaration static WITHIN a c function (as you can declare nested functions in C, even though as far as I can recall that doesn't have any real use case)? Just thought of that and wondering if that's at all possible and if it does anything (probably not in the standard anyway).

Comment: Your reasoning for why static function variables are bad is flawed. If you consider them as a global variable in disguise, then you are encapsulating the variable and encapsulation is usually a good thing. The main problem though is that the encapsulation is limited to one function (but that's just the language). I think the best reason to avoid static function variables, and by extension, global variables, is that they are not thread safe or re-entrant safe.

Comment: @Skizz: My reasoning is only flawed because of the situation you want to use them in yourself. Global variables as a general thing are mostly harmful. They are usually a bad practice if not used sparingly and in appropriate cases. And encapsulation is obviously good (same reason while static on functions is good, really), but it doesn't change the problem. It just makes it less visible. But I see your point with regard to thread safety.

Comment: @haylem: "error: invalid storage class for function" I learned something today!

Comment: @Nathon: Me too :) Thanks a lot for trying it out for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

In C `static` means two different things, actually:

1) inside a function it means that the `static` variable will remain in existence after the function has exited

2) otherwise it means that the `static` variable or function is local to that compilation unit (“file”), i.e. not externally visible

Comment: Downvote explanation? Surely this is not as verbose as the accepted answer, but the main points are the same.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable

In C a variable declared outside of functions as static will not be accessible from outside that file (can't use extern in another file..)

For a local variable in a function, static will make the lifetime of the variable last throughout execution of the program, not just a variable allocated on the stack.

When using static variables, it can really raise issues with multithreading because only one instance of the variable exists - so that needs to be kept in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what scope you are talking about.

Static inside a function, inside a class definition or in front of a global variable?

In a function it is good when you need to prevent a variable from being reinitialized. Below number of times will be 10.

```
  for(int z=0; z<10; z++)
  {
    static int number_of_times = 0;
    number_of_times++;
  }
```

Another use is when we need to preserve information about the last value a function returned.

If you wanted to number instances of a class, you can use a static member variable to keep track of them

Following that, static **member functions** can be used to modify static member variables to keep track of their values

Global static variables inside a file of code indicates other files that are part of the project cannot access the variable. Only the code in the file can. (simulate object oriented code)